# NgZone is not working as expected in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, zone

I m delaying user input to match with user typing, when I use `ngZone` service, it giving me error like

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of undefined
at questions-box.component.ts:111
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.754.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.754.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.754.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
at timer (zone.js:1540)
```

I have properly import and inject the ngZone Service in my component

here is snippet of my code

```
onCategoryChange() {
this.categorySearchTemp = null;
this._timeout = null;
if (this._timeout) {
  window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
}
this._timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
  this._timeout = null;
  this.lc.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.lc.run(() => {
      console.log("VALUE", this.categorySearch);
       this.getCategory(this.categorySearch);
    });
  });

}, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Why call the `zone` `lc`?

Answer (score 2):

use "fat arrow" function to preserve "this"

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {...}), 1000)
```

should be changed to

```
 window.setTimeout(()=> {...}), 1000)
```

Here is what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) says about "fat arrow" - "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. "

For example,

```
class A {

  callMeWithFatArrow() {
     setTimeout( () => {
        this.callThis();
    });
  }

  callMe() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            this.callThis();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('exception' + e);
        }
    });
  }

  callThis() {
    alert('i am here - callThis');
  }
}

let a = new A();
a.callMe();
a.callMeWithFatArrow();
```

callMe - will alert exception, because setTimeout use a regular function that sets its own this.

callMeWithFatArrow - will be able to call another method of class A inside of setTimeout becuase setTimeout in this case uses "fat arrow" that does not set its own this.

Comment: can you explain little more about use "fat arrow" function to preserve "this"